# C++ CLI How to access ByteArray from resources.resx

Tags: resources, c++-cli, clr, command-line-interface

So, I am quite new to C++ cli and I have worked with C# earlier. So, I am having hard time trying to use File::WriteAllBytes("Path", array ^bytes);

```
Resources::ResourceManager^ rm gcnew Resources::ResourceManager("unipatch.Resource",
    this->GetType()->Assembly);

array<Byte^> ^s = gcnew array<Byte^>(rm->GetObject("somedll"));
File::WriteAllBytes("path", s);
```

Comment: You are going to have to spend a couple of days learning basic syntax, this is not close.  Learning when to use the ^ hat is quite important.   Proper code is `array<Byte> ^s = safe_cast<array<Byte>^>(rm->GetObject("somedll"));`

Comment: @HansPassant I Sure do! Way I think is C++ cli syntax is bad, it's just ugly. But maybe I'll get used to it. Anyway, thanks for solving this for me!

Comment: It is eminently logical syntax, a direct consequence of preserving native C++ coding patterns, RAII first and foremost.  The language was very much designed to accommodate experienced C++ programmers.  If you have no prior C++ experience then it will take you a while to appreciate what they did, best to spend some time on that language first.